# How to install ONLY MySQL on Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) without MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, debian, google-compute-engine

When I install the MySQL it installs Maria's packages on the new Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), any suggestions?

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian Stretch (9.0) no longer includes MySQL . Some information on what's happening in the background when you try to install mysql-server is [available here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/moving-from-mysql-to-mariadb-in-debian-9/).

MariaDB is designed to be a fully compatible drop in replacement for MySQL but if you really want MySQL you should add the MySQL APT repository to your system [as described here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/). After adding the repository do an `apt update` and then proceed to install the mysql-server package.

Comment: If the answer solves your question please accept the answer so that the question stops showing up in the lists of questions people are seeking answers to. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  The official Debian repository for unstable/sid still includes mysql-server-5.7, which led to my mistaken answer.  As best I can tell it simply got pulled from stretch and the long-term intent is to support both implementations, so I updated the text of the question to match the facts