# Debian 9 how to install MariaDB without MySQL nameing?

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, debian-stretch

I'm going thru [this instrucion](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-and-DHT22-temperature-and-humidity-lo/), trying to keep data collected from DHT22 temperatur/humidity sensor on my RaspberryPi2 with Raspbian (Debian9) onboard.

But when it comes to install and use of the DB server, when i try to install MySQL, apt-get installs MariaDB.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417306/how-to-install-only-mysql-in-debian-gnu-linux-9-stretch-without-mariadb) and [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/moving-from-mysql-to-mariadb-in-debian-9/) link I know why, but i don't want to use MySQL name in my later scripts if my procedures really uses MariaDB.

So please tell my how change below commands to instal MariaDB directly, and login to DB interface without using MySQL name:

***sudo apt-get install mysql-server python-mysqldb***

***mysql -u root -p -h localhost***

Answer (score 0):

With those commands MariaDb is the default install for Debain 9. So all you need to do now is 
`apt-get install phpmyadmin` and `mysql_secure_installation`. Then you can login and access the interface at localhost/phpmyadmin