# Installing MySQL on debian using commandline

Tags: debian

I have been trying to install `mysql-server` on my debian machine for a while now, but so far I have run into many problems. I'm running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch).

I have tried:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

However, this installs `mariadb-server` (version 10.1, I need at least 10.2 for it to work) instead. I have tried updating my sources and adding apt-repo's but nothing allowed me to install the normal MySql. I have also tried install `MariaDB >= 10.2` directly but no luck either.

I would like either normal MySql-5.6 or MariaDB-10.3 on my machine. What do I do?

Comment: ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer (:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ONLY MySQL on Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) without MariaDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417306/how-to-install-only-mysql-on-debian-gnu-linux-9-stretch-without-mariadb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=shanghai-university&distro=Debian&distro_release=stretch--stretch&version=10.3)

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] https://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/mariadb/repo/10.3/debian stretch main'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

If You don't see Your distribution or cannot install by compatibility reasons only solution is to [compile from sources](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generic-build-instructions/)

Unfortunately I could not find `.DEB` package to ease Your life.

Comment: I have tried this but after the third command I get: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch

Comment: @CarloJacobs unfortunately You'll not find it. Since repo does not have Raspbian: https://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/mariadb/repo/10.3/

Comment: Compile from sources  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generic-build-instructions/